# Extend YAML pipeline example validate step

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

the extend template example shared by MSFT in documentation suppose to fail the step but it's not failing it.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/templates?view=azure-devops#extend-from-a-template

can anyone share a working example of this.

I want to to validate user yaml in extend template and fail the build in case of steps used that are not allowed as per firm policies.

Comment: May I know how the status of this after the weekend? Does below script is available for you? Free to comment if you still has any puzzle of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*The document here provides the confused direction. You can try to download your build log which does not action like you expect, then analyze the `initializeLog.txt` file contents. All of `key` evaluating expression are list there.*

Try with below sample:

**start.yml**

```
# File: start.yml
parameters:
- name: buildSteps # the name of the parameter is buildSteps
  type: stepList # data type is StepList
  default: [] # default value of buildSteps
stages:
- stage: secure_buildstage
  pool: Hosted VS2017
  jobs:
  - job: secure_buildjob
    steps:

    - script: echo This happens before code 
      displayName: 'Base: Pre-build'

    - script: echo Building
      displayName: 'Base: Build'

    - ${{ each step in parameters.buildSteps }}:
      - ${{ each pair in step }}:
          ${{ if ne(pair.value, 'CmdLine@2') }}:
            ${{ pair.key }}: ${{ pair.value }}       
          ${{ if eq(pair.value, 'CmdLine@2') }}: 
            '${{ pair.value }}': error         

    - script: echo This happens after code
      displayName: 'Base: Signing'
```

**azure-pipelines.yml**

```
trigger:
- master

extends:
  template: start.yml
  parameters:
    buildSteps:  
      - bash: echo Test #Passes
        displayName: succeed
      - bash: echo "Test"
        displayName: succeed
      - script: echo "Script Test" 
        displayName: Fail
```

Then you will see the pipeline failed because of the `script` step detected out:

[image]

**Note:** This validation is, once template detect out there has one `CmdLine@2` step was passed from `azure-pipeline.yml`, it will fail the current pipeline instead of one specified step.

[image]