# Checking if a task is added more than once inside a job - Azure yaml templates

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

We use the "extends" templates feature of Azure yaml pipelines for security purposes. One requirement we have is to not allow the use of a specific task inside a job more than once and if it happens, validation just should fail. I know I can iterate through the job steps and look for the existence of a specific task but is there a way to check how many times a task appears inside a job?

I checked length function but doesn't meet my needs as I'm not able to filter the steps for a specific task.

An example of a check we do today:

- ${{ each step in parameters.steps }}:

  - ${{ if contains(step.task, 'TaskA') }}:

    - 'TaskA is not allowed etc.' : error

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how you define the task in the yaml. It's recommended to check the definition, and avoid duplication of the tasks directly.

Or you could put the task in main yaml not the template, use sample script [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60768293/14996050) to validate the task in the template, if it exists, fail the pipeline.

Comment: Can you please clarify what you mean by check the definition and avoid duplication of the tasks directly? Users will add tasks in their yaml that extends from templates we manage and we want to check that user had not added the same task twice in a job inside the templates we manage. My goal is to not do it at runtime but at design time before even a run is attempted (i.e  yaml validation)

Comment: The yaml definition is sensitive and important, it's recommended to validate/control the yaml template if it's added by user but not yourself, use pull request..etc.  The extended template is expanded at compile time automatically by Azure DevOps service, i'm afraid there's no out of box to check for same tasks in the job at design(compile) time.